# Is there a formula for comparing 2 sheets with specific word then colored it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have 3 columns and I'm trying to compare column 2 and column 3 and then if the result is wrong column 1 will be colored red.

Can someone help me, please?

Example: I have Column Serial #, Column Items, & Column Status.
Column Items will compare to Column Status if the Status of particular Item is "NOT" the Serial # of that item will turn to red.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for cell color try this:

```
=IF(C2="NOT", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

for full row color use:

```
=IF($C2="NOT", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

for specific item:

```
=IF((C2="NOT")*(B2="PENCIL"), 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sir how about for specific item? for example i have multiple Items and i only want to highlight is PENCIL.